# Configuration similar to tomcat's timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis in Hikari

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, hikaricp

I'm currently migrating from Spring Boot 1.0 to 2.0.
SB2.0 changed the default DB Connection Pool to so configurations in application.yml file had to be modified too.

The tomcat config I'm having trouble to port is below:

```
test-while-idle: true
time-between-eviction-runs-millis: 3600000
```

`time-between-eviction-runs-millis` defines the [duration between idle cleaner thread to run](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html).
I've looked at [Hikari documents](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby) and either `idleTimeout` or `maxLifeTime` seems to be the right one to go with. But setting `idleTimeout` alone does not work since default `maxLifeTime` is shorter. According to the docs, `idleTimeout` should be meaningfully shorter than `maxLifeTime`.

This is where I'm lost. How do I set each value to achieve what I used to have as tomcat config?